# How to stop an app until a button is pressed?

Tags: wait

First sorry for my english!! =)
I'm doing a cards game for android and i have some troubles or questions better said.
I tried this code to implements an ActionListener to my ImageButtons (cards)
But i need that my app waits until some card were pressed. I thought using threads but i don't know how to do in my app. Can anyone help me?
Let my code in the following

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_juego);
        ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
        this.cartaenmesa = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        this.numcartasbaraja = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        this.numbar =2;
        this.numcartas = 20;
        this.numjug = 3;
        for(int i=0;i<=this.numjug-1;i++){
            this.jugadores.add(new Jugador("Jugador "+ i));

        }

        this.pilaInicial();
        this.desordenarPila();
        this.repartirInicial();
//      this.DibujarCartaEnMesa(this.pila.get(0));
//      this.DibujarCartas(this.jugadores.get(0).DevolverCartas());
//      this.numcartasbaraja.setText(""+this.pila.size());

        this.iniciarJuego();
    }
```

Here's the loop that set Listeners to all the buttons.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.imgbt_cartas_act.size();i++){
                    this.imgbt_cartas_act.get(i).setOnClickListener(listener); // AGREGAMOS LOS LISTENERS A CADA BOTON
                }
```

Here's where I assign an image and ID to the buttons

```
private void DibujarCartas (ArrayList<Carta> c){
        int i = 0;
        for (Carta c1 : c){
            this.imgbt_cartas_act.add(i, new ImageButton(Juego.this));
            //OROS
            if (c1.getValor()== 1 && c1.getPalo()=="Oros"){
                this.imgbt_cartas_act.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.oros_1);
                this.imgbt_cartas_act.get(i).setId(1);
            }
            if (c1.getValor()== 2 && c1.getPalo()=="Oros"){
                this.imgbt_cartas_act.get(i).setImageResource(R.drawable.oros_2);
                this.imgbt_cartas_act.get(i).setId(2);
            }
.......
}
```

and finally the OnClick

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //OROS
        if (v.getId()==1){ // 1 de oros
            carteleg = new Carta(1,"Oros");
        }
        if (v.getId()==2){ // 1 de oros
            carteleg = new Carta(2,"Oros");
        }
        if (v.getId()==3){ // 1 de oros
            carteleg = new Carta(3,"Oros");
        }
        if (v.getId()==4){ // 1 de oros
            carteleg = new Carta(4,"Oros");
        }
.....
    }
  };
```

Comment: Don't use threads here, they will just make the problem harder and do not sound relevant. Rather, to "stop" an event-based UI, simply don't fire the next action - that is, "continue with the application logic" *when* a button a pressed.

Comment: Thank you for answer! My problem is that all of this code is running in a loop while that controls the game and when it arrives to setOnclickListener codes keep running the next line. I need to stop the code until a card is pressed in that moment.